# Erro nas mensagens de validação Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, validação, view

Eu estou trabalhando com as mensagens de validação do Laravel, mas sempre esta me retornando "validation.min.string", deixei de importar algo?

Controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'telefone' => 'required|min:10|max:15'
    ], [
        'telefone.required'=>'Este campo é obrigatório'
    ]);
```

alerts.blade.php

```
@if($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <p>{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

View

```
@include('includes.alerts')
```

onde estou deixando de fazer algo?

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=372&v=OUzAfCXwbSA

Comment: Deu certo @CesarVinicius Obrigado!